# Changing Font style of textbox for just one line in C#

Tags: c#, fonts, textbox

Trying to change Font Style to Underline for 1 line,and printing next line in Regular Style is not working for me. I am trying something like this:-

```
    textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
    textBox1.Text+="This line should be underlined";
    textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    textBox1.Text+=Environment.NewLine;
    textBox1.Text+="This line should be normal";
```

But everything is coming only as it is done in the last line affecting FontStyle,in this case Regular. If I remove 3rd line,everything comes underline.

Answer (score 1):

A normal `TextBox` usually just supports one style. Its value is just a string, not a string with formatting information.

Instead, use a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) (WinForms)/[`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) (WPF).